# xcodebuild: error: 'APP.xcworkspace' does not exist

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, cocoapods, gitlab

I am trying to set up CI with gitlab. When I try to build locally, I get this error : `xcodebuild: error: 'APP.xcworkspace' does not exist.`
"APP" not being the real name. I am also using CocoaPods.

This happens after I run this command in terminal:
`gitlab-ci-multi-runner exec shell build_project`

I have checked and the file does exist in the same folder I call the command.

This is my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```yaml
stages:
  - build

build_project:
  stage: build
  script:
    - xcodebuild clean -workspace APP.xcworkspace -scheme APP | xcpretty
    - xcodebuild test -workspace APP.xcworkspace -scheme APP -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7,OS=10.2' | xcpretty -s
  tags:
    - v0.0.1
```

Xcode version: 8.2.1

Cocoapods version: 1.2.0

Gitlab-runner version : 1.11.0

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this now!!

I just had to update the cocoapods repo, se this link:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5077

> Looks like your specs repo was edited at some point, and now git can't update it. I'd recommend deleting and re-creating your Specs repo: `pod repo remove master` and running `pod setup`

Answer (score 3):

On React Native I've solved this issue by running command inside /ios folder.

Answer (score 1):

To share a scheme in Xcode:

1. Choose Product > Scheme > Manage Schemes.
2. Share your scheme:

   [image: screenshot showing "share" checkbox]
3. Click on the Close button.

Comment: That image was from the tutorial i used, so that didnt sove it as i already have done it

Answer (score 1):

In my case i had project with same folder name("Project") ending with 1 , 2 ,3 ,4 (total 5 folders). when i was trying to install cocoapods in "Project 4" Directory it was getting installed in "Project" instead it should be for "Project 4".

I could find Xcworkspace in the folder "Project"

Hence i need to delete other folders with same name and then install pods in "Project" folder