# ERROR: Runner.xcworkspace does not exist. error implementing google maps

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, flutter, dart

I'm trying to implement GoogleMaps into my flutter project, it works fine for the android version, but with the iOS version I'm facing some problems.

The error's title says:

> Runner.xcworkspace does not exist

This is the guide I'm following: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/google-maps-in-flutter/#4

I've done all of the steps in that guide, and I can see the file named `Runner.xcworkspace` in my project (using android studio), but still, I'm having this error.

The file inside `Runner.xcworkspace` is as below:

`Runner.xcworkspace` -> `xcshareddata` -> `WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>BuildSystemType</key>
    <string>Original</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Can you try the solutions in these threads? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42426358/xcodebuild-error-app-xcworkspace-does-not-exist & https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19482

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. I found this sample Github repository by Flutter themselves which helped solve the problem.

https://github.com/flutter/samples/tree/master/flutter_maps_firestore

Then in Runner/AppDelegate.m change the code to the following with your own API key.

```
#include "AppDelegate.h"
#include "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"
#import "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  // TODO: Replace this with an API key that has Google Maps for iOS enabled
  // See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/get-api-key
  [GMSServices provideAPIKey: @"ADD_A_KEY_HERE"];
  [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
  // Override point for customization after application launch.
  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

@end
```

To add Firestore support you will need to follow the process on Firebase and then add your own `Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist`

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to be running Xcode on mac to be able to get these files.

> Runner.xcworkspace contains the '*appid*' which can only be gotten when using Xcode